# failed connections in Azure Mariadb metrics

Tags: database, azure, mariadb, metrics, diagnostics

We are detecting several failed connections in our Azure Mariadb,I would like to know where are these failed connections coming from or maybe a query to further understand it, the Azure diagnostics doesn't seem to have much information: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IN9b.png)

AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == 'MySqlAuditLogs'
| where event_subclass_s  == 'ERROR'
| order by TimeGenerated desc

AzureMetrics
| where MetricName == "connections_failed"

AzureDiagnostics
| where event_class_s == "connection_log"
and event_subclass_s == "DISCONNECT"

I tried also querying slow_log and general_log in the database.
SELECT *
FROM mysql.slow_log
#WHERE event_name = 'connect'
where user_host NOT LIKE '%(successful)'
limit 30   0 row(s) returned   0.265 sec / 0.000 sec

AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == 'MySqlAuditLogs'
| where event_subclass_s  == 'ERROR'
| order by TimeGenerated desc

AzureMetrics
| where MetricName == "connections_failed"

AzureDiagnostics
| where event_class_s == "connection_log"
and event_subclass_s == "DISCONNECT"

I tried also querying slow_log and general_log in the database.
SELECT *
FROM mysql.slow_log
#WHERE event_name = 'connect'
where user_host NOT LIKE '%(successful)'
limit 30   0 row(s) returned   0.265 sec / 0.000 sec